# ADF Iteration inside table

Tags: oracle-adf

Hello I  have a list of objects that in turn includes a list. I would like to iterate over these in a table. Something like this.

```
<af:table value="#{backingBeanScope.evaluateBackingBean.subjects}"
var="subject">

<af:forEach var="course" items="${subject.courses}">

<af:column sortable="false"
headerText="#{evaluategyansokanviewcontrollerBundle.SUBJECT}"
id="colSubject" width="200">
<af:outputText value="#{subject.name}"id="ot2"/>
</af:column>

<af:column sortable="false"
headerText="#{evaluategyansokanviewcontrollerBundle.COURSE}"
id="colCourse">
<af:outputText value="#{course.name}"id="ot3"/>
</af:column>
```

...

I know this code doesn't work but its just to give an idea of what I want.

Regards
Johannes

Answer (score 0):

To me the easiest thing to do would be to actually flatten this out in Java before you get to rendering in JSF. Then you would just need "normal" syntax in your table. So maybe an ArrayList of courses by subject:

```
List<CourseBySubject> coursesBySubject;

public List<CourseBySubject> getCoursesBySubject() {
    if (coursesBySubject == null) {
        coursesBySubject = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Iterator<Subject> subjectIterator = subjects.iterator();
        while (subjectIterator.hasNext()) {
            Subject subject = subjectIterator.next();
            courses = subject.getCourses();
            Iterator<Course> courseIterator = courses.iterator();
            while (subjectIterator.hasNext()) {
                Course course = courseIterator.next();
                coursesBySubject.add(new CourseBySubject(subject.name, course.name));
            }
        }

    }
    return coursesBySubject;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for two layers of data - meaning a data with data or a collection with a subset of collections, then the af:table would not really be the ideal component to use.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might wana consider some of these questions first:

1. Is row selection important for you?
2. Is this more of a UI layout (read-only) vs a Data layout

If you're going more for a UI layout, then adf has two components that will go well with what you need:

- af:iterator
- af:foreach

Both are quite similar except that af:foreach only supports List types while iterator will provide flexibility when using with bindings.data.collectionModel for example.

One thing that is also worth mentioning is that af:foreach allows you to have component bindings while the af:iterator will represent nodes which means that the layout it generates will be only seen as one object in the server side.

I'll assume that you are looking for table based data with two levels and that rowselection is important for you. In that case, the af:treetable is your best bet since you get additional features such as collapse/uncollapse of parent rows.

If you're not using the bindings collectionModel (dataControl model) - which some might seem questionable - then make sure that you POJO collection provides accessors (setters) to the subset collection.

Eg.

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public abstract List<Country> getCountries();

    public static abstract class Country {
        public abstract List<City> getCities();
    }

    public static abstract class City {
    }
}
```

Just in case you are wondering why you can't use the af:table is mainly because the af:treeTable allows you selection of both parent and child and in fact, your bean can even distinguish the difference if the selection was against the parent vs the child.

With that said, you can also choose to use af:table and miss-out some af:treeTable features and probably rely on some custom attributes to distinguish what you are selecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an af:table within an af:table > af:column. Supported upto ADF 11.1.1.6 though.